# NoReverseMatch at / when redirecting

Tags: python, django

urls

```
url(r'^add/$', 'advice.views.add_new_advice'),
url(r'^$', 'advice.views.index'),
url(r'^(?P<advice_id>\d+)/$', 'advice.views.detail'),
```

views

```
def add_new_advice(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AdviceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_advice = form.cleaned_data["advice"]
            advice = Advice(advice = new_advice)
            advice.save()
            return redirect('detail', advice_id = advice.id)
    else:
        form = AdviceForm()

    return render_to_response("create.html", {"form" : form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def detail(request, advice_id):
    try:
        advice = Advice.objects.get(pk = advice_id)
    except Advice.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('index')

    return render_to_response("detail.html", {"advice" : advice})

def index(request):
    advices = Advice.objects.all()
    advice = choice(advices)

    return redirect('detail', advice_id = advice.id)
```

Hey, I've got this problem. Whenever it comes to redirecting to detail function I get NoReverseMatch at /. Please help.

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'advice_id': 7}' not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't call anything `"detail"` so it's not going to find it. Either add the name in your urls.py, use the full path to the function, or pass the function itself instead of a string.